# One git commit to all branches (Best Practice)

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have the same question that was answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459976/git-commit-to-all-branches) post, and I accept the answer, but I don't see a clear best practice. So, assuming the answer from the link remains valid (i.e. "do it manually"), I'll ask the question again in terms of what is the "best practice" to manually distribute a single change over a bushy tree (i.e. a lot of branches that all need the update). I imagine that it is an even more severe problem when there are remotes that you don't have access to.

For example, a config file has a bad setting at the very root of a project. Now someone spots that a consistent problem across the whole project is this config setting. So, they fix it and merge it...ah...where...how? There are 30 branches that he has access to and other remotes he does not??? Do you sit for half an hour with a list of all the branches and cross them off one by one as you cherry pick merge the commit? Send emails to the remotes? I don't see a good practice to follow.

Right now, I've been doing it piecemeal but I keep checking out branches and forgetting that they haven't been updated and suddenly get bitten by the damn setting...again and again! I have had this problem with changes to the Vagrantfile too. Basically any code that affects all branches becomes very inelastic.

I am new to git so perhaps I'm also overlooking some simple practice.  For example, I am thinking of putting a branch on the project in addition to the usual master/develop layout.  Something like master/develop/infrastructure.  It doesn't alleviate the problem but at least you don't have to cherry pick a commit to add to every branch every time something changes in the infrastructure, you can just pull in the whole infrastructure branch.

Comment: Git is designed to track source code.  Config files are not source code.  Using git to track config files is bad practice.  The solution to your problem is to stop using the bad practice of storing your config files in git.

Comment: @WilliamPursell config files *are* the source code, see DevOps. The other thing is that having config values for all environments in the same git branch as the main source can be inefficient, and it is usually beneficial to have a separate repository for those.

Comment: I agree with @WilliamPursell that I have to keep my Vagrant config at the least in source control.  I want all my developers working from the same environment, and this is a good way to "enforce" it.  But a question for William, are you saying I should keep two repositories, one for the vagrantfile and other infrastructure settings and one repository for the coded project?

Comment: No, I'm saying that config files are data, not source code.  It makes sense to have a history of your config files, but mixing that with source code for a project rarely makes sense.  But it really all depends on what sort of config files they are.  I think everyone would agree that RMS's .emacsrc does not belong in the source code for emacs.  It is entirely reasonable to have a separate repository for your environment, but it all depends on context.

Comment: Do you use Vagrant by any chance? It makes the development environment tied to the code you are developing very much like schema changes in a DB.  The schema is not code either, but you keep you schema changes in your repository, no?

Answer (score 3):

If this is your problem - you are using git incorrectly (albeit the project is not being efficient, or your not being efficient, whatever).  Almost all excepted "best practice" git flows have a single release branch that all other branches root from.  For instance, if you have a master branch and a develop branch, and all other branches are based off the develop branch.  Than all branches should be working towards merging into the develop branch.  Therefore, if you need to fix something for production quickly, you make the fix quickly in a brand new branch, than merge it into develop, and than merge develop in master.  Now the release is fixed - and the remaining branches can still be worked on.

In other words, if each branch is truly fixing and testing small parts of the code (i.e. distributed), they don't need the fixes from the other branches each branch should be working on mutually exclusive problems so they can always be independently merged without conflict.  Otherwise, your not truly using a distributed workflow, and you should probably be using a different source code manager.

Comment: You say "if you need to fix something for production quickly, you make the fix quickly in a brand new branch, than merge it into develop, and than merge develop in master.".  However, doing this forces me to pull develop into master which is rarely desirable before develop is ready.  However, my idea of a new branch "infrastructure" doesn't make sense. I could just merge the fix to develop and master, then always drag develop into whatever branch I'm working on. I still don't like it, but it may be the best way.

Comment: @EscapeArtist - the workflow with a develop merged to master is just one git flow.  The one I use often is just having master which is always production ready.  Than all other branches branch from master to work on mutually exclusive problems.  So for your example, you could create a branch call fix-config.  Than fix your config file and when it's debugged and tested - merge fix-config into master, and now the config problem is fixed for production.  All other branches can continue to work on their respective problems conflict free.

Comment: @EscapeArtist - here is a link to many common distributed git flows that work quite well:  http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows