# Make a change to all remote branches

Tags: git, github

I have a repository on github that has multiple working branches. There is a change that I would like to be added to all of the branches. The changes would merge cleanly into all active branches, so there's no issue there.

Is there a clean way to make this change so that all branches see it? Or do I have to make another branch and make a pull request into all of the branches I want to affect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git commit to all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459976/git-commit-to-all-branches)

Answer (score 0):

You can push a specific commit to multiple remote branches using:

```
$ git push origin <COMMIT_HASH>:{origin/branch1, origin/branch2}
```